# Does the rogue advanced talent, petrifying strike damage stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue

I want to know if the dex damage from this talent stacks for every sneak attack I do to the enemy.

> #### Petrifying Strike* (Su)
>
> Whenever the rogue damages a creature with one of her sneak attacks, she also deals 2 points of Dexterity damage to that creature as its body petrifies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. Ability damage is like hp damage — you deal it, and it happens instantaneously, “for real.” There’s no “effect” in place reducing their ability score; it’s simply been damaged, and has to heal in order to recover its original value. Thus, ability damage almost always stacks (and even when the rules say it doesn’t, that’s often pretty confusing).

Contrast this with ability *drain*, which **is** an ongoing effect that reduces an ability score. Applying the same ability-draining effect more than once would **not** stack.